# find one difference...(or more)

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I have two servers (debian). Almost identical. I want to use SSH AgentForwarding. 
I try to login from A to B and from B to A:

On user@A: set | grep SSH

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-uEsiAIsssn/agent.1234
SSH_CLIENT='1.2.3.4 34927 22'
SSH_CONNECTION='1.2.3.4 34927 5.6.7.8 22'
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
```

on user@B: set | grep SSH

```
SSH_CLIENT='5.6.7.8 35023 22'
SSH_CONNECTION='5.6.7.8 35023 1.2.3.4 22'
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/46
```

As you can see - there is SSH_AUTH_SOCK on server A (and this is good) - and there is not on server B (which is not good).

I'm grepping both servers searching SSH_AUTH_SOCK, but nothing found.

It is possible that I use some command on A which I don't use on B (or opposite), but now I can't find the difference in configuration.

I even copy putty save to exclude difference in inital SSH.

I think about ssh-agent, but why it works on A and doesn't work on B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always good to ask question. Next 30 second I found the solution, after 2 hours of searching...

The difference was in /etc/ssh/ssh_config, not sshd_config

This should be set to yes.

```
Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
ForwardAgent yes
```